# process number not displayed in background in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, background

```
<?php
while(true)
    {
    $reas ="wake up from sleep!!!!!!!!!! \n ";
    echo $reas;
    sleep(5);
   // $readlen = 0;
    }
?>
```

this is my code.
when i execute it ,it displays wake up from sleep
problem: when i run it in background,using

```
nohup php p2.php &
```

just the process number displays.but,when i give "top" command to check it in background,the process number is not found.could u say me what is the error. iam running in ubuntu.if i give kill 1234,it days "no such process"

i want to print the echo stmt in background with respect to the sleep time

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -aux | grep 1234
```

where 1234 is the process id. top shows the processes that are using the most CPU power, so the process you're looking for may be too far down the list.

Comment: i want to print the echo msg in background. if i use the above command,it does not print the echo stmt

Comment: Erm... what do you mean by printing the echo msg in the background?

Comment: i have given sleep as 5.so,for every 5 sec,the msg shoud be printed in background.and moreover,after execution ,if i give "kill 1234" it says "no such process".so, i think the process is not running

Comment: The process is in the background, so whatever it prints is invisible. If you want to see the output, don't run it in the background. Background means you don't see it running.

Comment: You can also send the output to a file, e.g. `nohup php p2.php > outputfile.txt &`

Comment: you can kill it, do a PS aux, record the process id, and do a kill, i just tried with your program.

Comment: when i try some other command,the process id is displayed in "top".for only this the process id is not displays in "top". i dont know y.pls help